# Error when sending a pull request to GitHub

Tags: git, github

So I'm very new to Github, and I'm using it for a Unity project with some friends who have also never used it before (We're using the Github API). We have it all set up and working, been going well for awhile now creating branches and making pull requests and such.

Now I have been working on a branch in which I created about 5 new Unity scenes and scripts. I tried sending a pull request to merge it with the master branch, but every time I try Github API freezes for a few hours and then throws an error, saying "Could not create pull request" and "Try manually synchronizing the current branch as well as the target branch and try again. If this error persists please email support@github.com.". Well, that would help if I even knew what "manually synchronizing the current branch as well as the target branch" means. Is it somehow wanting me to merge the branch in question with my local master (Which I don't know how to do) and then sync with the remote repo? I don't understand. Help please!

Comment: By GitHub API do you mean GitHub GUI tool, like this? https://windows.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are yo using a specific GitHub API for Unity? if you have been using it i guess you have already set unity to use it with a github repository, you could upload manually downloading [github for windows](https://windows.github.com/) (if you are using windows), there you can upload the folder of unity project with the GUI of using the git commandline ([github command cheatsheet](https://training.github.com/kit/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf)), anyway, with a simple `git commit -a -m "comment"` and `git push` (or pull) you should be able to manually upload the project to github (if any problem with repo sync or something, it will tell you instead of crashing and you could find the exact solution)

Answer (score 0):

> pull request to merge it with the master branch

What you are trying to do is most probably a push request:

```
git branch <feature_name>
git add <files>
git add <more files>
git commit -m'explaining message'
git push origin my_branch_name
```

In short terms, you have to learn about git workflow. Try pushing and pulling by each own, with a separate testing repository. When you're comfortable with that, try branching and merging branches. Then make a branch conflict and resolve it.

When you work in a team, never push to master! Work on a separate branch for each person and feature. It would also be good to have one person, responsible for Git operation. They would do the merges to master and resolve conflicts.

Also note that Unity scenes are essentially binary files. They can not be merged automatically and even `git diff` has no human-readable effect on them. Build your team workflow so that no scene is worked upon by two or more people.

To get more comfortable with Git, please read references and do tutorials. They're plenty on the [git tag "about" page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info).

[Another cheatsheet](http://www.ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html#loc=remote_repo;).

Answer (score 0):

I tried what demiurgosoft suggested, but it just crashed the console, so I tried dropping the files manually into my local master repo, and then syncing with the remote master repo. That too threw an error, but this time it alerted me to conflicting files ending in .sln, from where I was able to notice that I had a typo in .gitignore causing conflicts.

And thanks for the advice Nick Volynkin, we'll be sure to do that.